# What exactly does "AttributeError: temp instance has no attribute '__getitem__'" mean?

Tags: python, class, attributeerror

I'm trying to understand a problem I'm having with python 2.7 right now.

Here is my code from the file test.py:

```
class temp:
 def __init__(self):
  self = dict()
  self[1] = 'bla'
```

Then, on the terminal, I enter:

```
from test import temp
a=temp
```

if I enter `a` I get this:

```
>>> a
<test.temp instance at 0x10e3387e8>
```

And if I try to read `a[1]`, I get this:

```
>>> a[1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: temp instance has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Are you trying to subclass `dict`, or something like that?

Comment: I had some code that runs as a dictionary and I don't want to change that... Now I will to make a class out of it.

Comment: You've really confused things with your editing and comments. Originally, you were getting a TypeError. Now you're saying you are getting AttributeError (which is not consistent with other parts of what you wrote; for example, you probably meant that you do `a()` and not just `a`). Then you've got a comment to kindall's answer that says you modified your code, but you didn't update your question. So it's really all just a mess and the very first thing you should do at this point is really clean up your question.

Comment: But to literally answer the question of "What does `AttributeError: temp instance has no attribute '__getitem__'` mean?" the answer is that you are trying to do indexing or key lookup (via the square brackets in `a[1]`) yet `a` (which is an instance of `temp`) does not have indexing or key lookup defined (because that behavior would be defined in the special `__getitem__` method, and `a` has no such method, nor does it inherit such a method from a parent class).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, the code you posted cannot yield the error you noted. You have not instantiated the class; `a` is merely another name for `temp`. So your actual error message will be:

```
TypeError: 'classobj' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Even if you instantiate it (`a = temp()`) it still won't do what you seem to expect. Assigning `self = dict()` merely changes the value of the variable `self` within your `__init__()` method; it does not do anything to the instance. When the `__init__()` method ends, this variable goes away, since you did not store it anywhere else.

It seems as if you might want to subclass `dict` instead:

```
class temp(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        self[1] = 'bla'
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I updated the line class `temp(dict)`. Now `a` is a dict and not an `instance`, but it steel does not have my `bla` on `a[1]`...

Comment: I using `class temp(dict):` (new line) `def __init__(self):` (new line) `self = dict() ` (new line) `self[1] = 'bla'`

Comment: You don't need the `self = dict()` line. `self` is already your dictionary, that's the whole point of making it a subclass.